# How to update SQLITE Database with new JSON Values

Tags: java, android, json, database, sqlite

I am having some difficult time trying to update my database with new JSON objects.

I am trying to do a Currecy App. So, whenever it is connected to internet or currency changes, it has to update the JSON data in the SQLite Database.

Otherwise, take the old data from the database.

To read files to database, I have this method:

```
private void readDataToDb(SQLiteDatabase db) throws IOException, JSONException {


    final String MNU_NAME = "name";
    final String MNU_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    final String MNU_PRICE = "price";
    final String MNU_CATEGORY = "category";
    final String MNU_PHOTO = "photo";

    try {
        String jsonDataString = readJsonDataFromFile();
        JSONArray menuItemsJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonDataString);

        for (int i = 0; i < menuItemsJsonArray.length(); ++i) {

            String name;
            String description;
            String price;
            String category;
            String photo;


            JSONObject menuItemObject = menuItemsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


            name = menuItemObject.getString(MNU_NAME);
            description = menuItemObject.getString(MNU_DESCRIPTION);
            price = menuItemObject.getString(MNU_PRICE);
            category = menuItemObject.getString(MNU_CATEGORY);
            photo = menuItemObject.getString(MNU_PHOTO);


            ContentValues menuValues = new ContentValues();

            menuValues.put(DbContract.MenuEntry.COLUMN_NAME, name);
            menuValues.put(DbContract.MenuEntry.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);
            menuValues.put(DbContract.MenuEntry.COLUMN_PRICE, price);
            menuValues.put(DbContract.MenuEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY, category);
            menuValues.put(DbContract.MenuEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO, photo);

            db.insert(DbContract.MenuEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, menuValues);




            Log.d(TAG, "Inserted Successfully " + menuValues );
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And in onCreate method in DBHelper:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    final String SQL_CREATE_BUGS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DbContract.MenuEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            DbContract.MenuEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            DbContract.MenuEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
            DbContract.MenuEntry.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            DbContract.MenuEntry.COLUMN_PRICE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            DbContract.MenuEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            DbContract.MenuEntry.COLUMN_PHOTO + " INTEGER NOT NULL " + " );";


    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CURRENCY_TABLE);
    Log.d(TAG, "Database Created Successfully" );


    try {
        readDataToDb(db);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

I tried to find a solution for update also using,

```
db.update(DbContract.MenuEntry.TABLE_NAME, menuValues, null,null);
```

in order to use in another method and then using it in Oncreate but it did not work out.

As I have read, changing database version every time in the app and using it on onUpgrade method helps but is it the right approach to constantly changing database version ?

To sum up:

What would be the easiest way to update the database when JSON file changes?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Check android documentation https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html